# I'm trying to remove duplicate data from a new array, but am returning array of individual characters instead. What can I do differently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, object

I have an array of objects saved to:

```
const arrayOfCustomerObjects
```

I need to return an array of States based on an array of objects that lists data including address information. In addition, each state should only be listed once. Duplicates must be removed from the final array.

I believe I was able to access the state information successfully using dot notation. I was having issues figuring out how to return an array where there is no repeating data, and my research leads me to the `[...new Set()]` approach. The outcome of this is an array that not only does not remove the duplicates but also returns each individual character in the state names as a new array. Here is the code I am currently using:

```js
const arrayOfCustomerObjects = [{
  "profile": {
    "name": {
      "first": "Lucille",
      "last": "Bradshaw"
    },
    "address": {
      "line1": "91 Juliana Place",
      "line2": "Apt 226",
      "city": "Homeworth",
      "state": "Ohio"
    }
  }
}];


function getUniqueListOfAllCustomerStates(data) {
  let stateArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let state = data[i].profile.address.state;
    let uniqueState = [...new Set(state)];
    stateArray.push(uniqueState);
    console.log(uniqueState)
  }
  return stateArray;
}
console.log(getUniqueListOfAllCustomerStates(arrayOfCustomerObjects));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're running `[...new Set(state)]` where `state` is the string of each individual state name. This will just remove duplicate letters in each state's name, then an array of those unique letters.

Instead, you want to map `arrayOfCustomerObjects` so that each element is the state name with `data.map(x => x.profile.address.state)`. With that array of the states of every customer, you can then run the `...Set` trick to remove duplicate state name's:

```js
const arrayOfCustomerObjects = [{
  "profile": {
    "name": {
      "first": "Lucille",
      "last": "Bradshaw"
    },
    "address": {
      "line1": "91 Juliana Place",
      "line2": "Apt 226",
      "city": "Homeworth",
      "state": "Ohio"
    }
  }
}, {
  "profile": {
    "name": {
      "first": "Lucille",
      "last": "Bradshaw"
    },
    "address": {
      "line1": "91 Juliana Place",
      "line2": "Apt 226",
      "city": "Homeworth",
      "state": "Ohio"
    }
  }
}, {
  "profile": {
    "name": {
      "first": "Lucille",
      "last": "Bradshaw"
    },
    "address": {
      "line1": "91 Juliana Place",
      "line2": "Apt 226",
      "city": "Homeworth",
      "state": "Illinois"
    }
  }
}];


function getUniqueListOfAllCustomerStates(data) {
  return [...new Set(data.map(x => x.profile.address.state))];
}
console.log(getUniqueListOfAllCustomerStates(arrayOfCustomerObjects));
```